# Как в sqlite сделать select по времени unixtime?

Tags: select, sqlite3

Есть база `SQLite`. Нужно запросом вынуть из нее данные по 1 таблице `test` за последние 15 минут. Время находится в таблице `last_visit_time` в формате `unixtime`.

#### last_visit_time

13093097142949097

13093097142949097

13093694538560880

13093102824969089

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
SELECT last_visit_time
FROM table
WHERE last_visit_time > strftime('%s','now') - 900 000;
```